# How to randomly spawn turtles

Tags: netlogo

I'm pretty new at NetLogo and coding

At the moment I am trying to make a bio-economical modell of fishery for my bachelor-thesis.

The basic model is working pretty good but I do have 1 problem:

at one point there are not enough fish left to make the boats stay in my system.( they just "die out")

Is it possible to just randomly spawn some boats, if there aren't any left, to solve that problem and how do i write it in my code?

thanks for als answers .

Edit:

the basicaly Problem I have, is that I don't know how to code this with NetLogo.

```
to
  random-spawn
  if count boats = 0
  [breed 1 [rt random-float 360 fd 1]]
end
```

I just need another command instead of breed. (hatch isn't possible because there are no boats left and breed can't be right

Comment: Seems your model is bad, not a programming problem. My guess at the algorithm problem you have is that fishing boats don't die out when there is no fish they have a much slower lifecycle.

Comment: So boats die out because there are no fish? Presumably this is based on rules about fishers going and getting another job when they can't make a living. This sounds like the interesting result for a research question (what is a sustainable level of fishing?) rather than a problem. But easiest thing to do would be to have a slider that gives a probability each tick of creating a boat.

Comment: @JenB  yeah that sounds great, but how do i put in such a slider?

Comment: please do the online tutorial at the NetLogo site as it's not something I can explain here. Once you have a slider, then something like `if random-float 1 < slider-name [ ask one-of patches [ sprout boat 1 ] ]`